# My button does not save the form to the database. Help please

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to save this form for an attendance website. But whenever I clicked the clock in button it does not save the data to the database.

code:

```
 if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST) 
        if response.POST.get("clockIn"):
            if form.is_valid():
                n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                t = Name(name = n, timeIn=datetime.now())
                t.save()    
 else: 
        form = CreateNewList()        
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {"form":form})
```

html button code:

```
 <button type="submit" ,name="clockIn", value="time In" class="btn-success">Clock In</button>
```

I have also tried using this:

```
if 'clockIn' in response.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                t = Name(name = n, timeIn=datetime.now())
                t.save()
```

It still does not work. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be `comma(,)` between the attributes in html tag. So:

```
 <button type="submit" name="clockIn" value="time In" class="btn-success">Clock In</button>
```

Comment: @Din Don't forget to upvote or accept answer if your problem is solved. It helps others understand if they should still search for answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: I need to wait 5 min for some reason but I will accept ur answer. Again thank you very much